# What do "static" and "non-static" mean in the context of Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, middleware

The [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express) for Express's `express.static()` middleware states:

> To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express.

It seems that the JS files for dynamic React apps are included, since `express.static("some_build_dir")` seems to work even when `some_build_dir` is a front-end React app.

However, it seems natural that React apps which use JS to dynamically generate web content should be considered *dynamic*, rather than *static*, so there's something I'm missing here.

**Q**: What kinds of things does Express actually consider "non-static" or "dynamic", then, if even the source files of React apps do not qualify?

Comment: "Static" basically means actual files on the filesystem. What happens on the client isn't relevant.

Comment: @GuyIncognito So, just to confirm, the definition of "static" in the context of Express is different from that of "static" in the phrase "static web-page", is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Express doesn't know or care what the client does with the stuff it sends there.

Comment: For servers, static files are those which are not 'parsed' by server e.g. javascripts, stylesheets, images, documents etc.  Express does not run javascript in your build directory. Express directly serves it to client unlike the javascript in your server javascript files. I know it's confusing at the start, so +1ed to counter downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static: Files that the web server (Express) reads from the file system and sends, unmodified, to the client.

Non-static: Responses that are programmatically generated (e.g. from a template with data from a database being inserted into it).

---

> However, it seems natural that React apps which use JS to dynamically generate web content should be considered dynamic, rather than static, so there's something I'm missing here.

As far as the server is concerned, the JS source code and bootstrap HTML file that it sends to the client **are** static. The dynamic part of them is handled client-side which is outside the server's control.

Answer (score 0):

static middleware means it is a static file or folders, and it is a true. the react app is static, the code not changed, the same index.html will serve to user as static file then the content will changed with user interactions and api requests but still the source of files the same and not changed